# Sublattice of an Atomic Lattice

Tags: discrete-mathematics, lattice-orders

Is the sublattice of an atomic lattice atomic? If not, then what additional condition is necessary for a sublattice to be atomic?

Comment: What is your definition of atomic lattice? (It's not obvious because you don't show any work and/or context.) Usually, a lattice is said to be atomic if every element in that lattice is above one atom (at least). Some authors call atomic to a lattice where every element is a join of atoms; to those, I call *atomistic*.

Comment: Let $\mathbb Q$ be the totally ordered set of rational numbers and let $L={\mathcal P}(\mathbb Q)$ be the lattice of subsets of $\mathbb Q$ under inclusion. $L$ is atomic/atomistic, but $\mathbb Q$ is a nonatomic lattice embeddable in $L$ ($f\colon {\mathbb Q}\to L\colon q\mapsto (\infty,q]$). The image of this map is a nonatomic sublattice of an atomic/atomistic lattice.

Comment: A lattice is said to be atomic if every element in that lattice is above one atom. I am using this definition.

Comment: Is this true for finite lattices?

Comment: It is true for finite lattices (indeed, every finite lattice is atomic, and each of its sub-lattices is also finite...). For the general case, Keith Kearnes already gave a counter-example.

Comment: Where can I find the proof that every finite lattice is atomic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Theorem.** The following are equivalent for a lattice $L$.

1. Every sublattice of $L$ is atomic.
2. $L$ satisfies the descending chain condition (DCC).

[A lattice satisfies the DCC iff it has no infinite strictly descending chain iff any nonempty subset of $L$ has a minimal element. Every finite lattice satisfies the DCC, since a finite lattice cannot contain an infinite strictly decreasing chain.]

**Reasoning.**
Assume that $K$ is a lattice that satisfies the DCC.
For any $x\in K-\{0\}$, the nonempty half-open interval $(0,x]$ must have a minimal element $y$. Necessarily $y$ is an atom of $K$ below $x$. Thus, if $K$ satisfies the DCC, then $K$ is atomic.

Now assume that Item $2$ of the theorem is true for some lattice $L$. Since any sublattice of a DCC lattice also satisfies the DCC, any sublattice of $L$ is atomic. Hence Item $1$ of the theorem is true.

Next, assume that Item $2$ fails, then $L$ contains an infinite subset $C = \{x_0, x_1, \ldots\}\subseteq L$ with $x_0>x_1>\cdots$.
 $C$ is a sublattice of $L$ that has no atoms, so it is a nonatomic sublattice of $L$. Hence Item $1$ fails. \\\

Comment: Thank you for the proof.

Comment: @MehakBatra Better than thanking with a comment, is to accept the answer, when you're happy with it. When you have enough reputation, you can also upvote it (see that number two: it's two upvotes). See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers), and more generally, take the [Tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) and see also [Help](https://math.stackexchange.com/help). These links are at the bottom of the page.